# Comparing two documents using regex

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

I want to compare two documents irrespective of line breaks. If the content is the same but the position and quantity of line breaks are different, I want to map the lines in one document to the lines in the other.

Given:

Document 1

```
I went to Paris in July 15, where I met some nice people.
And I came back
to NY in Aug 15.
I am planning
to go there soon
after I finish what I do.
```

Document 2

```
I went
to Paris
in July 15,
where I met
some nice people.
And I came back to NY in Aug 15.
I am planning to go
there soon after I finish what I do.
```

I want an algorithm capable of determining that line 1 in Document 1 contains the same text as lines 1 through 5 in Document 2, that lines 2 and 3 in Document 1 contain the same text as line 6 in Document 2, etc.

```
1 = 1,2,3,4,5
2,3 = 6
4,5,6 = 7,8
```

Is there a way with regex to match each line in each document if it spans over multiple lines in the other documents?

Comment: One approach would be to just split both inputs into words, maintaining the lines they came from, and the just correspond the words one-by-one (assuming the words are the same).

Comment: the lines that are matching from each document

Comment: If you haven't take the time to think through your problem well enough to explain it properly, then you probably haven't taken enough time to think through your problem.

Comment: I tried to clear up the intent of your question. If I've butchered it, you can "rollback" to the previous version using the editor.

Comment: Thanks @Cyborgx37, probably I needed more clarification, I think your attempt is a good one

Comment: Now that the question is clearer, can you show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) so far?

Comment: **Update**

It boils down to trying to match each line if it spans over multiple lines:

pattern='I went to Paris in July 15, where I met some nice people.'
pat=re.compile(pattern,re.MULTILINE)
matching=[v.span() for v in pat.finditer(doc2_text)]
somehow the multiline thing doesn't work

Comment: In my experience, `re.DOTALL` (which treats newlines as regular characters) is the thing to use when we think of "multiline". I suggest you to give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Compare {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String doc1 = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("Doc1.txt"));
        String doc2 = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("Doc2.txt"));
        String[] array1 = doc1.split("\n");
        String[] array2 = doc2.split("\n");
        int[] count1 = new int[array1.length];
        int[] count2 = new int[array2.length];
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<count1.length;i++) {
            count1[i] = sum1 + array1[i].split(" ").length;
            sum1 = count1[i];
        }
        for (int i=0;i<count2.length;i++) {
            count2[i] = sum2 + array2[i].split(" ").length;
            sum2 = count2[i];
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> result1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> result2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int j=0; j<count1.length; ) {
            for (int k=0; k<count2.length; ) {
                if (count1[j]==count2[k]) {
                    result1.add(j+1);
                    result2.add(k+1);
                    System.out.println(result1.toString()+" = "+result2.toString());
                    result1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    result2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    j++;k++;
                } else if (count1[j]>count2[k]) {
                    result2.add(k+1);
                    k++;
                } else {
                    result1.add(j+1);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
[1] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3] = [6]
[4, 5, 6] = [7, 8]
```

Complete and working Java code. It's not a regex solution, so it might not fit your need.

The idea is that we create an array for each document. The size of the array equals the number of lines in each document. The nth element of the array stores the number of words seen up to the nth line of the document. Then we identify those equal elements in both arrays, whose indices define the ranges of the output.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a python programmer, but this does not look like a problem that can be solved with regex.

Instead, you'd first want to compare the documents to make sure the content is the same (temporarily remove all newlines beforehand). I don't know what you want done if it isn't, so I'm not going to address that.

Create a collection of integer collections called `linemappings`

Begin a loop. The loop will step through each character in each document simultaneously. You'll need four counter variables. `charindex1` will contain the current character index in Document 1 and `charindex2` will contain the current charater index in Document 2. `lineindex1` will contain the current line index in Document 1 and `lineindex2` will contain the current line index in Document 2.

Start with the char index variables to 0 and the line index variables initialized to 1.

> Start Loop:
>
> > Get the current character from each document: `char1` from document 1 and `char2` from document 2.
> >
> > If `char1` AND `char2` are BOTH newlines or NEITHER are newlines, then advance both `charindex1` and `charindex2` by 1.
> >     Else If `char1` is a newline, then advance `charindex1` by 1.
> >     Else If `char2` is a newline, then advance `charindex2` by 1.
> >
> > If EITHER `char1` or `char2` is a newline, then insert a new record into the `linemappings` collection (the result at the end will be something like `[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,6],[3,6],[4,7],[5,7],[6,7],[6,8]`)
> >
> > If `char1` is a newline, advance `lineindex1` by 1.
> >     If `char2` is a newline, advance `lineindex2` by 1.
>
> Loop until the end of input is reached.

(I couldn't really test this since I'm not a python programmer, but hopefully you get the gist and can modify it to fit your needs.)

Comment: @TerryLi has a better answer. I'd go with that, personally.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each line of doc1 and do something like this:

`searchstring = line.replace(' ', '[ |\n]')`

Then do a search on doc2 using this search string.

`match = re.search(searchstring, contents)`

If `match` is `NULL`, then there was no match.
Else, `match.group(0)` will give you the matching contents of doc 2.

`'I went\nto Paris\nin July 15,\nwhere I met\nsome nice people.'`

Then it's a simple exercise of splitting that by '\n' and figuring out which lines in doc2 they came from.